# echo function inside function bug

Tags: php, html, function

I have the following PHP code:

```
function button1($attr, $text) {
  $data = "<button ";

  foreach($attr as $names => $specs) {
    $data .= $names . "='" . $specs . "' ";
  }

  $data .= ">" . $text . "</button>\n";
  echo $data;
}

function span1($attr, $text) {
  $data = "<span ";

  foreach($attr as $names => $specs) {
    $data .= $names . "='" . $specs . "' ";
  }

  $data .= ">" . $text . "</span>\n";
  echo $data;
}

button1(
  array( "type" => "button",
         "class" => "navbar-toggle",
         "data-toggle" => "collapse",
         "data-target" => ".navbar-collapse"
  ),
  span1(
    array( "class" => "sr-only" ),
    "Toggle navigation"
  )
);
```

From the code above, I want the result to appear like this:

```
<button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse' >
  <span class='sr-only' >Toggle navigation</span>
</button>
```

But instead it appears like this:

```
<span class='sr-only' >Toggle navigation</span>
<button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse' ></button>
```

What must I do to get the result I want? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at this: http://codepad.org/uQCHutPx

Comment: @rohit great, thanks for the answer, it works for me but i feel annoying if i must include the ECHO in my views one by one, because of this i use echo in my function. any advice?

Comment: You should study about function execution

Comment: As per your code:
First call to button1 function inside this span1 function will execute.
If echo anything span1 function then it will echo first.
Then execution of button1 will take place.If echo anything button1 function then it will echo.
So the output like that as you are getting from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, **NEVER** `echo` from functions. The problem is, `span1()` is being evaluate first which results in its `echo` executing. It also returns nothing to be used as the `button1()` `$text` argument. Then the `button1()` `echo` is executed, printing its contents to the output stream **after** the `span1()` echo.

Change the last line of each function to

```
return $data;
```

and execute it via

```
echo button1(...);
```

Comment: great, thanks for the answer, it works for me and now i know the rules of function is never echo from that but i feel annoying if i must include the ECHO in my views one by one, because of this i use echo in my function, any advice?

Comment: @MuhammadZaidTaufiq In an MVC pattern, *views* are where output is generated so that's where the `echo` should be.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your PHP code with this,
You have to `return $data` into functions and also echo button1();

```
<?php 

function button1($attr, $text) {
  $data = "<button ";

  foreach($attr as $names => $specs) {
    $data .= $names . "='" . $specs . "' ";
}

  $data .= ">" . $text . "</button>\n";
return $data;
}

function span1($attr, $text) {
  $data = "<span ";

  foreach($attr as $names => $specs) {
    $data .= $names . "='" . $specs . "' ";
  }

  $data .= ">" . $text . "</span>\n";
  return $data;
}

echo button1(
  array( "type" => "button",
         "class" => "navbar-toggle",
         "data-toggle" => "collapse",
         "data-target" => ".navbar-collapse" ),
  span1(
    array( "class" => "sr-only" ),
    "Toggle navigation"
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello use below code for your desired output
    function button1($attr, $text) 
    {
        $data = "

```
    foreach($attr as $names => $specs) 
    {
         $data .= $names . "='" . $specs . "' ";
    }

    $data .= ">" . $text . "</button>\n";
    return $data;
}

function span1($attr, $text) 
{
     $data = "<span ";

     foreach($attr as $names => $specs) 
     {
          $data .= $names . "='" . $specs . "' ";
     }

     $data .= ">" . $text . "</span>\n";
     return $data;
}

$str = span1(
         array( "class" => "sr-only" ),
                "Toggle navigation"
        );
```

echo button1(
          array( "type" => "button",
                 "class" => "navbar-toggle",
                 "data-toggle" => "collapse",
                 "data-target" => ".navbar-collapse"
                ),
                 $str
    );